# Printing : HasMorePages not works With For Loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop

I am developing WFA application in C#. I am trying to print more pages. But i can not more than one page. I have used for loop. Everything seems good but my code not working after first page. Here is my code;

```
float currentY = 10;
        currentY = currentY + 15;
        for (totalnumber = 0; totalnumber < 100; totalnumber += 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(totalnumber.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 50, currentY);
            currentY += 20;
            if (itemperpage < 20) 
            {
                itemperpage += 1; 
                e.HasMorePages = false; 

            }

            else if (itemperpage == 20) 
            {
                itemperpage = 0; 
                e.HasMorePages = true; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code is missing a *return* after setting HasMorePages to *true*.  The "totalnumber" variable must be declared outside of the method.  You need the BeginPrint event to initialize it to 0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done them. But it returns infinity loop for number of page.

Comment: I have done it with while loop by using BeginPrint event. Thanks once.